# Crash: Snap with dependency to WebRTC

Tags: snap

Would rely on your assistance.

I'm trying to create a snap (via `snapcraft`), but its execution is failed because of

```
# Fatal error in: ../../media/engine/adm_helpers.cc, line 39
# last system error: 88
# Check failed: 0 == adm->Init() (0 vs. -1)
# Failed to initialize the ADM.
```

As I've understood from https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/C3o0-NWqdn4, it's relevant to the usage of WebRTC.

May you help to inject the dependency into the `snapcraft.yaml` configuration file (haven't found anything relevant on https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-interfaces):

```yaml
name: fingrom
base: core22

grade: stable
confinement: strict

apps:
  fingrom:
    command: fingrom
    plugs: [home, desktop, desktop-legacy, network, network-bind, opengl, x11]
    extensions: [gnome]

parts:
  app-finance:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    build-packages: [libgtk-3-dev, ninja-build]
    stage-packages: [libgtk-3-0]
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Devmode is not helping to identify the issue (`snap install fingrom --devmode`), app is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not actually obvious, but `audio-playback` is needed for WebRTC

```yaml
environment:
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ${SNAP}/usr/lib/$SNAPCRAFT_ARCH_TRIPLET/pulseaudio

apps:
  __:
    plugs: 
      - audio-playback

stage-packages: 
 - libpulse0
```